# Google sheets add-on: create doGet and doPost endpoints

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to build an add-on where in the user installs add-on and during configuration, I need to generate `doGet` and `doPost` URL's (web app endpoints) to which user can post data.

From my research to generate `doGet` and `doPost` API URLs, the script has to be deployed as a web app from a particular user account.

Is it possible to deploy `doGet` and `doPost` code inside my add-on as web app from the installed Sheets add-on?

Comment: The script can know its own url, yes. And you can make a webapp run as the user accessing, e.g. so they have access to their own Drive, Sheets, Docs, Gmail. You can't programmatically generate code on installation though. A sidebar can simply use the google.script.run communication method to run server functions.

Comment: any relevant link to which you can point me to. I couldn't find any specific details regarding the same.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#getUrl()  It's probably worthwhile for you to include the purpose of `doGet` and `doPost` in your add-on, since being able to run server functions from the HTML should do basically everything that having `doGet` and `doPost` can do for you as well.

Comment: what I am looking for is, once user installs the add-on on and clicks a button on side bar, I need generate doPost and doGet url for him, which he can use to post content. Usually if this is a stand-alone script, the user goes to script editor > publish > deploy as webapp - which gives url of end point to get or post content.Can this be done with some code inside add-on.

Comment: Quote from Apps Script API documentation:  **The Apps Script API allows your apps to perform operations that previously could only be done in the Apps Script editor.**  Your add-on *could* use the Apps Script API.  Of course, the user must be willing to authorize permissions.  If you want a unique published Web App URL for every user, then you can't run the `doGet()` or `doPost()` functions from your add-on.  Only you can publish a web app from the script that you own, which means that every user would be using the same Web App URL.  Your add-on could put a new Apps Script file on their Drive.

Comment: But if the Apps Script file is on their Drive, then they are the owner, and if you want to protect any code in that Apps Script file from being discovered, you need to put a library that you own into that Apps Script file with private function names.  If you don't use private function names, then there is a way to discover the function names, and read the function code.  I'm assuming that what you want to achieve, is to get code to run that is using their resources, and not going against your quota, but also protecting your code?

Comment: @SandyGood yes. exactly. This is the use case: user installs addon - runs addon code that deploys a script containing doPost() to their account and shows them the url of the deployed script - which they use as a webhook

Comment: `  var svc = ScriptApp.getService();
  svc.enable(svc.Restriction.MYSELF);
  a = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
` generates url, but the problem is url generated is the same when created from multiple accounts.

Comment: This is a situation that I have thought about, but I haven't deployed code that would do this.  I'm guessing that there are probably 2 or 3 different ways you could try to do this, but I don't know the pros and cons of every possible solution.  If the user is willing to do some minimal set up, it might make it easier for you to implement.  If you want it totally automated, I'm not sure if that is possible.  Although, I'm guessing that it might be with the Apps Script API.  You could ask the user to add your library to a Web App that they own, and ask them to publish the web app themselves.

Comment: @justanotherguy you should update your post to clarify your goals, what you've tried, etc.